# NSArrays and NSDictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am having a problem with `NSdictionary` and `NSArray`. What I am trying to accomplish is have one `UILabel` that will repeat itself with different data within a loop. The data is coming from an xml file. I'm parsing the data correctly, I got it to show up using:

```
lblAffected = [[[outageDict objectForKey:@"Outage" ]objectForKey:@"outagenum" ]objectForKey:@"text" ];
```

My problem comes when I have multiple outage numbers associated with one outage. Below is what I currently have.

```
if (mapCoordinateIsInPolygon) {
    int outageIndex = [poly.title intValue];
    NSDictionary *outageDict = [sections objectAtIndex:outageIndex];
    //NSLog(@"hit, outageDict = %@", outageDict);

    for (NSDictionary *data in outageDict){
        NSArray *outageData = [outageDict objectForKey:@"Outage" ];
        NSMutableArray *outageInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(NSDictionary *outa in outageData){
            [outageInfo addObject:[[outa objectForKey:@"outagenum"] objectForKey:@"text"]];
            NSLog(@"ouatage %@", outageInfo);
        }
        int add = 0;
        NSLog(@"ouatage %i", [outageInfo count]);
        for (int i=0; i < [outageInfo count]; i++){
        add = add+20;
        lblAffected.frame = CGRectMake(130,add,320, 60);
        NSLog(@"added : %i",add);
        lblAffected.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblAffected.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        lblAffected.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size: 13.0];
        lblAffected.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        lblAffected.numberOfLines = 1;

        lblAffected.text = outageInfo[i];
        NSLog(@"outage Ifo %@",outageInfo[i]);
        [headerView addSubview:lblAffected];
    }
}
```

What needs to happen is once I get the data from outageDict it needs to be stored inside the label and showed on the subView. In case there are multiple outage numbers the label needs to duplicate itself showing all outage numbers 20px beneath each other. I will eventually place it inside a scrollView but for know I'm just trying to fix this.

Now my question is what am I doing wrong on the dictionary and arrays? When I touch the polygonview on the map with multiple outages it shows up in the log file but when I tap one with only one outage it crashes. Am I going about this the wrong way? The Error message is happening at

```
[outageInfo addObject:[[outa objectForKey:@"outagenum"] objectForKey:@"text"]];
```

and states that

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d2b160
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry is there something wrong with my question as to why it's getting a done vote?

Comment: What line is it crashing on, and what is the error message?

Comment: outageenum is likely no dict :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are getting is self-explanatory.

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d2b160
```

You have a string object (`__NSCFString`) and you're treating it as a dictionary by calling `objectForKey:` on it. Since a string does not understand this method (or selector), you're getting the exception `"unrecognized selector sent to instance"`.

The line at which you're getting this exception contains two distinct calls to `objectForKey:`, and the exception could be from either of those.

```
[outageInfo addObject:[[outa objectForKey:@"outagenum"] objectForKey:@"text"]];
```

The two objects on which you're calling `objectForKey:` here are:

1. `outa`
2. `[outa objectForKey:@"outagenum"]`

To find out if it's the first one or the second one, set a breakpoint on the line where you're seeing the exception or crash. Then, once the debugger halts execution on that line, inspect the data types of both these objects. At the lldb or gdb cursor, type these commands to inspect the problematic objects. `po` stands for print object, and it prints a description of the object in question.

```
(lldb) po outa
(lldb) po [outa objectForKey:@"outagenum"]
```

That should tell you which one of those two is a string object.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint on [outageInfo addObject:[[outa objectForKey:@"outagenum"] objectForKey:@"text"]];

Comment: Just put a breakpoint on [outageInfo addObject:[[outa objectForKey:@"outagenum"] objectForKey:@"text"]];     then  in log try the following (lldb) po [outa class]  and (lldb) po [[outa objectForKey:@"outagenum"] class]   it well tell you the class type for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of object you are setting for key outagenum at outa (assuming it is a dictionary)
[outageInfo addObject:[[outa objectForKey:@"outagenum"] objectForKey:@"text"]];

That is string or dictionary?